# Iterate an RLMArray in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I'm using Realm Objective-C in a mixed ObjC/Swift project.

I do have a variable which holds an RLMArray where Media is an RMLObject as well.

I would like to iterate through this array with a classic iterator such as

```
let medias: RLMArray<Media>
for media in medias {
    //Use media as a Media object.
}
```

However, Swift compiler reject this syntax with error:

```
Type 'RLMArray<Media>' does not not conform to protocol 'Sequence'
```

Please help on iterating through an RLMArray in Swift.

Comment: I'm using `import RealmSwift`... why not you?

Comment: RealmSwift is only for pure swift projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy [RLMSupport.swift](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/Swift/RLMSupport.swift) to your project. It includes refinement for Objective-C and Swift interoperability. There is a comformance `RLMArray` to `Sequence` in it.

Comment: Thanks! It works but the object in the iterator is an 'RLMIterator.Element' instead of a 'Media'. Then I have to cast it manually in the iterator. Any way of getting directly a 'Media" instance directly ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you need to cast 